# How to set up a centralised authentication site like google?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, customization

how to design a website only for storing user data and use the same for login into any alias website like google. For example **`accounts.website.com`** is used for new user sign-up or existing user authentication. Then I have two more websites, first one is used as e-commerce store and another is used for service/support. When the user tries to signup or login they will be redirected to accounts.website.com and after finishing authentication they will be redirected to previous website. Same process is followed from the second website. Any idea how? Any article or guide?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "Single Sign-On" (SSO). If you're only having two sites at maximum I'm wondering if a WordPress multisite installation isn't better suited for this as opposed to setting up a third SSO server / VM for user authentication.

Comment: Yeah I am getting the point now. Thanks for your answer..

Comment: As I know Wordpress multisite installation works with a single domain, here I have two separate domains. If you have any guide on implementation and design of SSO would you able to share it with me?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with 3 separate WordPress sites:-

1. accounts
2. e-commerce
3. support

Install the [WP OAuth server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/) on the *accounts* site.

And [Single Sign Client](https://wordpress.org/plugins/single-sign-on-client/) on the *e-commerce* and *support* sites.